# Best practice for shared variable in javascript object

Tags: javascript

Declaring a variable inside a javascript method seems to scope it to the window-object, is there any way to change that behaviour?

```
var mf = new Array();

mf.init = function () {
    oldIh = 10;
    this.oldIh = 20;
    alert(oldIh); //outputs 10, would prefer 20...
    alert(window.oldIh); //outputs 10.        
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), where an error would be thrown if you forget to use var to declare a variable.

Comment: I would argue that `oldIh = 10;` doesn't "declare" a variable, what you're doing is setting an undefined variable, and the compiler is doing the best it can to interpret this.

Comment: If i use var without this, I can't find a way to reach it

Comment: When you say _"If i use var without this, I can't find a way to reach it"_ .... Question: Reach it from where?

Comment: @LGSon, from another method.

Comment: Posted an answer where you could do this `mf.oldIh` to get it, though after you last comment I start wonder if that was not what you wanted..? ... also added a 2nd sample, showing how an arrow function would work, still, not sure if that help either

Comment: Let me know if the given answer is useful, or I simply delete it.

Comment: It's useful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's quite confusing..

1) Using *var* is not allowed for declaring *this.varaibleName*

2) Using *var* inside method defines a method-only variable.

3) Not using *var* nor *this* creates a window-variable (not allowed in strict-mode)

4) The solution is to use *this.variableName* without *var* which is perfectly fine even in **strict mode**.

```
'use strict';

var mf = new Array();

mf.init = function () {
    this.oldIh = window.innerHeight;
    //Not allowed:
    //var this.oldIh = window.innerHeight;
    //
    //Creates a var for this method only
    //var oldIh = 123;
    //
    //Creates a window-variable (not allowed in strict mode)
    //oldIh = 123;
}

mf.getInnerHeight = function () {
  return this.oldIh;
}

mf.init();
alert(mf.getInnerHeight());
```

Thanks to everyone contributing to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment, if you want to access the *inner `this.oldIh`* from outside, simply use its function variable, like this

Stack snippet

```js
var mf = new Array();

mf.init = function () {
    oldIh = 10;
    this.oldIh = 20;
}

mf.init();

console.log(oldIh)
console.log(mf.oldIh)
```

---

If you would use an arrow function, the `this` would in this case refer to the global scope and change the value, and it will be accessible w/o the function variable.

Stack snippet

```js
var mf = new Array();

mf.init = () => {
    oldIh = 10;
    this.oldIh = 20;
}

mf.init();

console.log(oldIh)
```

Comment: Thanks, I summarized the situation in a new answer. Please comment or upvote as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `var` or `let`

```js
var mf = new Array();

mf.init = function () {
    let oldIh = 10;
    this.oldIh = 20;
    alert(oldIh); //outputs 10
    alert(window.oldIh); //outputs undefined      
}

mf.init();
```

Comment: Nope, those are not the same...as you can see

Comment: @LGSon - I am unable to find the difference in the said example, can you please explain?

Comment: Thanks, but const doesn't fit for the purpose.

Comment: The `this.oldIh = 20;` won't change the `const oldIh` to `20`

Comment: @LGSon - Yes. It was not supposed to change too. I just got rid of `const` because OP stated `does not fit for the purpose` which means that variable will be updated later and also followed by your comment, which somehow hinted a update in value. If my understanding is not in sync, request you to provide some details.

Comment: Well, the OP wrote in their sample code `alert(oldIh); //outputs 10, would prefer 20...`, so how does this answer solve that?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for helping out. Yes, the value might change so const doesn't fit. Maybe it's to much to ask for that var xx, without object prefix shoud be visible anywhere outside the function scope. What did confuse me was probably JS falling back to the window object when not using var.

Comment: @LGSon - Ohh! I was targeting the question asked `Declaring a variable inside a javascript method seems to scope it to the window-object, is there any way to change that behaviour?`. I ignored the question in comment. Additionally, you can not have the changed value in log by keeping 2 variables one that is function scoped and the other that is a property of object. I think that is not possible without changing the structure and that will be governed by the requirement.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Right :)